# Cant get `ion-nav-view` to work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I tried to implement the `ion-nav-view` from Ionic so i could get a toolbar which is similar to the Android Native Toolbar. For that i followed the instructions described [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/).

So i created the following index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <!-- Ionic -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- myApp -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/factory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

And this app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    }).state('prints', {
        url: '/prints',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_prints.html'
    }).state('box', {
        url: '/box',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_box.html'
    }).state('framed', {
        url: '/framed',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_framed.html'
    }).state('xxl', {
        url: '/xxl',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_xxl.html'
    }).state('collage', {
        url: '/collage',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_collage.html'
    }).state('coupon', {
        url: '/coupon',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_coupon.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

To show an example here the views/home.html:

```
<script id="home" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content ng-controller="HomeController">
            <a href="#/prints">Prints</a>
            <a href="#/box">Box</a>
            <a href="#/book">Book</a>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
```

But when i now start the app all i can see is the following:

[image]

The documentation says the following:

> Then on app start, $stateProvider will look at the url, see it matches the index state, and then try to load home.html into the `<ion-nav-view>`.

So either the app is not in index state when i start it or i have another mistake. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You only need the ng-template if you define the template in your index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `home.html` should be plain html, it should not use `<script id="home" type="text/ng-template">`, 
Because of `ng-template` type it will create a template with its URL `home` & will put it inside `$templateCache` of angular

Removing script tag from there will fix your issue. I think you have made same mistake for other html too

**Home.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeController">
        <a href="#/prints">Prints</a>
        <a href="#/box">Box</a>
        <a href="#/book">Book</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: @Makz Glad to hear that, it helped you as well, Thanks :)